# how do I convert an xml string to an object. I don't know what object ahead of time. Just several possibities

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a string of that is an XML string and it could correspond to one of several objects that are jaxb generated schema files.
I don't know what object it is ahead of time.

- How do convert this XML string to an jaxb xml object? Some type of unmarshalling?
- How do I determine which object it is assigned to?
- How do I instantiate the object once it is converted from xml string to the object?

Comment: Asking your question once is sufficient, I think. Can you show a typical XML file? Possible objects obtained? Your current code attempts? Other details of your problem?

Comment: We're going to need a little more than that. An example of the different messages to start with.

Comment: The message objects are jaxb generated schema files

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like the following:

**Foo**

As long as there is a root element associated with your class via an `@XmlRootElement` or `@XmlElementDecl` annotation you don't need to specify the type of class that you are unmarshalling (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html).

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

To unmarshal from a `String` simply wrap the `String` in an instance of `StringReader`.  The `unmarshal` operation will convert the XML into an instance of your domain class.  If you don't know what class you will have to use `instanceof` or `getClass()` to determine what type it is.

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        String xml = "<foo><bar>Hello World</bar></foo>";
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Object result = unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

        if(result instanceof Foo) {
            Foo foo = (Foo) result;
            System.out.println(foo.getBar());
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Unmarshaller yourunmarshaller = JAXBContext.NewInstance(yourClass).createUnMarshaller();
JAXBElement<YourType> jaxb = (yourunmarshaller).unmarshal(XMLUtils.getStringSource([your object]), [the class of your object].class);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have schema files for the XML objects, which you would if you're using JAXB, run a validate on the XML.

[Java XML validation against XSD Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396903/java-xml-validation-against-xsd-schema)

Comment: JAXB (JSR-222) implementations do not require that you have a XML schema.  JAXB is designed to start from Java classes:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

Answer (score 0):

If you generate objects from XSD, then JAXB generated an ObjectFactory class in the same package as all the type classes.

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("your.package.name");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
```

Here "your.package.name" stands for the package name of your ObjectFactory class.

The unmarshaller can now convert your XML into objects:

```
public Object createObjectFromString(String messageBody) throws JAXBException {
    return unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(messageBody));
}
```

If this is successful, a JAXBElement object will be returned:

```
try {
    JAXBElement jaxbElement= (JAXBElement) createObjectFromString(messageBody);
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    // unmarshalling was not successful, take care of the return object 
}
```

If you have a `jaxbElement` object returned, you can call `getValue()` for the wrapped object, of `getDeclaredType()` for it's class.

With this method, you don't need to know the type of the target object in advance.