# XML Schema validation containing ASSERT Tag

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate a XML instance with a XML Schema which contains an `assert` tag in it. The validator throws an exception containing the message:

> The content of '#AnonType_message' is invalid.  Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

This is my code:

```
//xmlData is a xml string
Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(new StringReader( xmlData ));

SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);

Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

validator.validate(xmlFile);
```

This is the parser's error message:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Answer (score 2):

The `<assert>` tag is valid in XSD 1.1 schemas.

To validate your schema you will need a XSD 1.1 compatible parser. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20807066/how-to-validate-xml-against-xsd-1-1-in-java) and the answer for an example on how to configure it in your application.

You might also want to check if your XSD document has these two attributes in the `<xs:schema>` start tag:

```
<xs:schema ...
       xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1" ...>
```

Comment: question link is not linked properly.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to include it. You might also want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819060/xml-validation-against-xsd-1-1-with-xerces-in-java