# XSD 1.1 validation for both Java and .NET C#?

Tags: java, c#, xml, xsd, xsd-1.1

I have an XSD with schema version 1.1, and I want to validate an XML against it programmatically via .NET and Java.

In .NET I use `XmlSchemaSet` class to validate XML against XSD, but it throws the following exception:

> `System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException: The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:assert' element is not supported in this context.

So I guess .NET still supports XSD 1.0 and doesn't support XSD 1.1 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct, .NET supports XSD 1.0, not XSD 1.1.  You can use [Xerces to validate XML against XSD 1.1 in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819060/xml-validation-against-xsd-1-1-with-xerces-in-java), but there are no free libraries that support XSD 1.1 on .NET.

To validate XML using XSD 1.1 on .NET, you'll need a commercial license for Saxon EE (full product) or EE-V (validation package).  Note that a Saxon license will allow you to use the library on both .NET and Java platforms.  See Saxonica's [product page](http://www.saxonica.com/products/products.xml), [feature matrix](http://www.saxonica.com/products/feature-matrix-10.xml), and [licensing](http://www.saxonica.com/license/license.xml) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to this question because it has taken me years to find a solution for .Net that didn't cost anything, which was a condition for me though not for this question. The link provided by kjhughes covers the first half of the question, performing validation in Java.

Below I am using the excellent [IKVM project](https://github.com/ikvmnet/ikvm) to reference xerces2-j directly to handle the .Net side of the question. I am using the download, [Xerces-J-bin.2.12.2-xml-schema-1.1.zip](https://dlcdn.apache.org//xerces/j/binaries/Xerces-J-bin.2.12.2-xml-schema-1.1.zip).

The solution requires four jar files from xerces, which are kept in the subfolder named 'include' in this project folder.

1. cupv10k-runtime.jar
2. org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor_1.2.1.jar
3. xercesImpl.jar
4. xml-apis.jar

Then this must be added to the project file for IKVM to do its thing.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="IKVM" Version="8.7.1" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <IkvmReference Include="include\org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor_1.2.1.jar">
        <AssemblyName>eclipse-xpath2</AssemblyName>
        <AssemblyVersion>1.2.1.0</AssemblyVersion>
        <AssemblyFileVersion>1.2.1.0</AssemblyFileVersion>
    </IkvmReference>
    <IkvmReference Include="include\cupv10k-runtime.jar">
        <AssemblyName>cup-runtime</AssemblyName>
        <AssemblyVersion>0.10.0</AssemblyVersion>
        <AssemblyFileVersion>0.10.0</AssemblyFileVersion>
    </IkvmReference>
    <IkvmReference Include="include\xml-apis.jar">
        <AssemblyName>xml-apis</AssemblyName>
        <AssemblyVersion>1.7.0</AssemblyVersion>
        <AssemblyFileVersion>1.7.0</AssemblyFileVersion>
    </IkvmReference>
    <IkvmReference Include="include\xercesImpl.jar">
        <AssemblyName>xerces</AssemblyName>
        <AssemblyVersion>2.12.2.0</AssemblyVersion>
        <AssemblyFileVersion>2.12.2.0</AssemblyFileVersion>
        <References>include/cupv10k-runtime.jar;include/org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor_1.2.1.jar;include/xml-apis.jar</References>
    </IkvmReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then this simple program.cs will validate xml properly.

```
using javax.xml.transform;
using javax.xml.transform.stream;
using jio = java.io;
using javax.xml.validation;
using org.apache.xerces.impl;
using org.xml.sax;
using System.Reflection;
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ikvm.runtime.Startup.addBootClassPathAssembly(Assembly.Load("eclipse-xpath2"));
        ikvm.runtime.Startup.addBootClassPathAssembly(Assembly.Load("cup-runtime"));
        ikvm.runtime.Startup.addBootClassPathAssembly(Assembly.Load("xml-apis"));
        ikvm.runtime.Startup.addBootClassPathAssembly(Assembly.Load("xerces"));
        
        jio.File schemaLocation = new jio.File("/path/to/some.xsd");
        jio.File xmlFile        = new jio.File("/path/to/some.xml");

        Source xsdSource = new StreamSource(schemaLocation);
        Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(xmlFile);

        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(Constants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA11_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(xsdSource);
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();


        try
        {
            validator.validate(xmlSource);
            Console.WriteLine(xmlFile.getName() + " is valid.");
        }
        catch (SAXException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(xmlFile.getName() + " is not valid because ");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```